# Wiener filter coefficients for time series

Tags: time-series, filter

I am tasked to find the wiener coefficients for a time series forecasting dataset with daily seasonality. I split the dataset into 24hour segments an find the wiener coefficients between day N and day N+1 using day N for the autocor matrix and dayn and dayN+1 for crosscor vector. The final solution has 24 coefficients. How would i use them? If i plot the coefficients (there are 500 days so arround 500sets of coefficients) what information can i extract?